# Checking for an empty Future set

Tags: java

I have a Future variable that returns a set of objects. And I'm trying to take some action if that set is not empty. I tried doing oosSignal.get() which throws an exception, and I also tried doing Future.value(oosSignal) which says that types are not compatible. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Future<Set<InternalPinResult>> oosSignal =
        pinsListFuture
            .flatMap(func((Pair<FeedSourceIdentifier, List<InternalPinResult>> pair) -> {
              List<InternalPinResult> pinsCopy = pair.getSecond() != null
                                                 ? Lists.newArrayList(pair.getSecond())
                                                 : null;
              return Future.value(pinsCopy.stream().filter((InternalPinResult pin) ->
                  pin != null
                      && blah).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
            }));

    System.out.println();
    // Activate the stock signal experiment only if user has atleast 1 out of stock pin.
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Future.value(oosSignal))) {
      # do something
    }
```

Stack trace with .get()

```
at com.twitter.util.Function$$anon$3.apply(Function.scala:57)

at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:893)

at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:892)

at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:100)

at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.k(Promise.scala:100)

at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.apply(Promise.scala:110)

at com.twitter.util.Promise$Transformer.apply(Promise.scala:91)

at com.twitter.util.Promise$$anon$3.run(Promise.scala:691)

at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler$Activation.run(Scheduler.scala:187)

at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler$Activation.flush(Scheduler.scala:164)

at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler.flush(Scheduler.scala:217)

at com.twitter.concurrent.Scheduler$.flush(Scheduler.scala:85)

at com.twitter.util.Promise.ready(Promise.scala:534)

at com.twitter.util.Promise.result(Promise.scala:541)

at com.twitter.util.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(Awaitable.scala:100)

at com.twitter.concurrent.LocalScheduler.blocking(Scheduler.scala:229)

at com.twitter.concurrent.Scheduler$.blocking(Scheduler.scala:91)

at com.twitter.util.Await$.result(Awaitable.scala:100)

at com.twitter.util.Future.get(Future.scala:722)

at com.pinterest.smartfeed.contentgenerator.FeedSourceContentFetcher.lambda$getAvailableFromFeedSources$13(FeedSourceContentFetcher.java:469)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exception are you getting? Show us your stack trace. Also, what's `Future.value()`?

Comment: That's not the full stack trace; you're missing the actual exception. Also, we can't identify the line numbers.